# Extract columns from large xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have 7gb xml file. From the data I am trying extract the The primary accession , The primary protein name as columns and save it as a csv file.

I am new to python. I have 7gb xml file and trying to parse the data as columns and save it in a csv file. I am finding a way to parse this huge file. [image: sample xml screen shot] [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxSED.png)

I tried to use

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
tree = ElementTree.parse(.xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
```

The above python code takes a longer time to process 7gb file. I want some help to know if there is any alternative where i can extract the following information as columns and save it as a csv file.

Comment: Try looking at [How to Read XML File with Python and Pandas](https://datascientyst.com/read-xml-file-python-pandas/).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don’t share xml text file as picture. Can you extract a possible example part and share it as a valid xml in text format. Explain what content you are interested. How should the csv look like? There is a tour how to ask on this forum. Btw you first and your last tow lines of code read the 7GB into RAM, pandas isn’t used but imported. Please share a minimal working example, what demonstrate your question.

Comment: How often do you need to parse the file?  If you do not need to do often than who cares how long it takes!  You have a huge file and most XML libraries would give an out of memory exception.  You are lucky that the code runs without exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `iterparse` of pandas [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), specifically meant to read large files for memory efficient parsing using the same named method of `lxml` (default `parser`) and `etree` libraries.

```py
protein_df = pd.read_xml(
    "uniprot_sprot.xml", iterparse={"entry": ["accession", "name"]}
)
```

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-xml) indicate this method able to read in Wikipedia's 12GB XML dump!

Answer (score 2):

Not clear, what content you are interested in. Here one example, what you can do with `iterparse()` to write a csv-file:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

level = 0
for event, elem in ET.iterparse('Protein.xml', events=('start','end',)):
    # print(level, elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text)
    if event == 'start':
        level += 1
    if event == 'end':
        level -= 1
        if elem.tag == '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}accession':
            accession = elem.text
        if elem.tag == '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}name' and level == 2:
            name2 = elem.text
        if elem.tag == '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}fullName':
            fullName = elem.text
        if elem.tag == '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}name' and elem.get('type') == 'ordered locus' and level == 4:
            name4 = elem.text
        if elem.tag == '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}name' and elem.get('type') == 'scientific' and level == 4:
            name5 = elem.text
        if elem.tag == '{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}name' and elem.get('type') == 'common' and level == 4:
            name6 = elem.text

            row = accession, name2, fullName, name4, name5, name6
            with open('protein.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                protwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                protwriter.writerow(row)

            elem.clear()
```

Writes in a csv file:

```
"P0C9F0";"1001R_ASFK5";"Protein MGF 100-1R";"Ken-018";"African swine fever virus (isolate Pig/Kenya/KEN-50/1950)";"ASFV"
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the valuable information.